# How to add ID attribute field for Menu's UI Admin page?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

[image]

Hi

In Wordpress, if you go to Appearance -> Menus, you will see the above list of pages you set up for your navigation menus to appear.

Under Menu Structure, if you click on one of your pages, you will see only two attributes available for the page ie navigation label and title attribute.  I would like to include another field called 'ID Attribute' for the page.

Does anybody know in Wordpress how can I extend the navigation functionality to include this new field on the UI admin page?

Look forward to hearing your suggestions.

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.wpexplorer.com/adding-custom-attributes-to-wordpress-menus/

Comment: you can add class, Is this fine with class?

Comment: Class is okay. But I want some elements on my pages to have unique element names so when I do my css styling, the styles won't get mixed up with other div tags sharing the same class attribute names.

Comment: Thanks Sankalp.  That looks useful!  However, I've already added my Twitter Bootstrap Responsive Menu walker into my code.  http://www.pattonwebz.com/wordpress-custom/bootstrap-wordpress-responsive-menu/  So how can I add another one to the walker setup?

Comment: @AW-GWTF899 The link you posted is actually from my website, so firstly thanks for reading one of my tutorials :D If you had dropped this question into the comments box on the site I would have been happy to help you out with it. If you were to follow the WP Explorer tutorial linked in the first comment then it's nice and easy to just grab the value of it and place it in the ID of the menu item. I'll write you up some code to do it and post back here.

Comment: Hi William, Sorry for the late reply.  No worries.  I thoroughly enjoyed the tutorial you wrote.  It's exactly what I need to get the nav menus to work in Wordpress environment! :) Can you perhaps drop me  a few lines of code how I can add the ID as the menu item.  That would be good.  How can I reach you?

Comment: Try this http://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/